# MATLAB Updating a global variable from one function does not get reflected in the other function

Tags: function, matlab, global-variables, updates

I have a function that uses a global variable and I want to change its value from another function. Even though I tried in many ways, the function that uses the value seems not getting updated with the new value of the global variable. Here's the code I'm using.

**calculate.m**

```
function calculateTest()

global isStop;
global value;

value=0;
while ~isStop
    pause(1);
    value = value+1
end

end
```

**start.m**

```
function start()

global isStop;
isStop = 0;
calculateTest();
end
```

**stop.m**

```
function stop()

global isStop;
isStop = 1;
end
```

When I call start() the value starts getting printed. But even if I call stop(), it never stops. It keeps on printing. Do you have any idea of what I am missing?

(I have tried *while isStop==0* as well. But the result was the same.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is a *background thread* that would do the `calculateTest` while leaving you the possibility to run `stop` from a matlab script/command line. This functionality is not supported by MATLAB in the pure sense. You can sometimes implement similar things using the [`timer`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/timer.html) functionality. Essentially, you tell MATLAB to run a function repeatedly after some time has passed. However, MATLAB is running the timer function in the foreground. And while it is doing that you can not run your `stop` script. So you can not implement a long loop in the timer function. `timer` is only good to schedule some tasks to be executed by MATLAB every now and then, but does not implement threading.

You could implement your own background thread using a MEX function. You could then call the MEX function to pass `'start'/'stop'` commands to your thread. But the MEX thread would have to do the data processing inside. You can not e.g. call some matlab script to do the job.

Another thing. `start` and `stop` are MATLAB functions that manage the timer. Do not use those identifiers as names of your own functions - that is allowed, but considered a bad practice.

Comment: Hi angainor, Thanks for the advices. Ultimately I wanted to create a dll out of the functions and call them in C#. Just to check the above, I created two separate dlls one with calculateTest() and one with stop() And I called them in two seperate threads in C#. Still the same results. So I will read on MEX as you have mentioned and see whether it helps. Any other suggestions, if any are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: (What I ultimately want is to read a global variable that is updated by a continuously running function and show the value in a .NET gui whenever I want. and the ability to stop that function when a button is clicked)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't actually called the stop function anywhere in your code, so there is no opportunity for it to update the global variable.

You could, for example, modify calculateTest() by adding a conditional test which calls the stop function when "**value**" reaches a certain number, such as 5:-

```
function calculateTest()

global isStop;
global value;

value=0;
while ~isStop
    pause(1);
    value = value+1
    if value == 5
        stop;
    end
end

end
```

You will find that this stops it perfectly well.  If you added the stop command into start instead, after CalculateTest, that will not work because the flow of control never reaches that line - it remains on CalculateTest until that function is terminated.

Comment: Hi Nik....Thanks for reasoning why it was not working. That makes sense. But my actual requirement was to cal a function that continuously calculates FFT of an input signal. And I want to stop it when ever I want. (Not on a predefined condition) That's for what I thought of using a separate function. Is this not possible?